# JavaFX: Change cell color after adding new row to the table

Tags: javafx, tableview, row

I have a program that reads certain files and then displays the values in a table. The user can add new rows via a button.

Now I want to change the background color of the added line so that it is visible to the user what is new and what is old.

My question now is, how can I select the new line directly and then change the background color?

I know you how to get a single cell position with the class **TablePosition**.

**Example**

```
TablePosition pos = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
int row = pos.getRow();
int col = pos.getColumn();
TableColumn column = pos.getTableColumn();
```

But how does it works if I want the entire row?

**Expected Result**

In the end I expect that I can the added row gets selected so that I can change the background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a observable collection you can store the new items in. `ObservableSet` does the job pretty well.

Furthermore create a custom `rowFactory` for the `TableView`. Rows created by the factory update the style every time the item or the collection changes. This allows you to pretty easily modify the selected items.

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // bad design here, but this type is not important
    class Item {
        final StringProperty value;

        Item(String value) {
            this.value = new SimpleStringProperty(value);
        }
    }

    TableView<Item> table = new TableView();

    TableColumn<Item, String> column = new TableColumn<>("value");
    column.setCellValueFactory(i -> i.getValue().value);
    table.getColumns().add(column);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        table.getItems().add(new Item(Integer.toString(i)));
    }

    // set storing items to be marked as new
    final ObservableSet<Item> newItems = FXCollections.observableSet(new HashSet<>());

    final PseudoClass newPc = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("new");
    table.setRowFactory(t -> new TableRow<Item>() {

        private final InvalidationListener l = o -> update();

        // prevent memory leak for cells that are "thrown away"
        private final WeakInvalidationListener listener = new WeakInvalidationListener(l);

        {
            newItems.addListener(listener);
        }

        private void update() {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(newPc, isEmpty() || newItems.contains(getItem()));
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            update();
        }

    });

    // create buttons modifying the new items

    Button addButton = new Button("add");
    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        int counter = 20;

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++, counter++) {
                Item item = new Item(Integer.toString(counter));
                newItems.add(item);
                table.getItems().add(item);
            }
        }

    });

    Button clearNew = new Button("clear new");
    clearNew.setOnAction(evt -> newItems.clear());

    Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(table, new VBox(addButton, clearNew)));
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/path/to/my/style.css").toString());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

**style.css**

```css
.table-row-cell:new {
    -fx-background: #DDDD00;
}

.table-row-cell:new:selected {
    -fx-background: #BBBB00;
}
```